# Android: Create image button with a non-clickable overlarge overlay when focused?

Tags: android, user-interface, layout, overlay, imageview

For a new Android project I need buttons which are 'shining' when focused or pressed, meaning a bigger image should show up on top of the first image. My problem here is: The clickable area should be not as large as this overlay image.

In ASCII-Art:

```
+------------------------------------------+
|                                          |
|                                          |
|         +---------------------+          |
|         | Inner image, always |          |
|         | visible & clickable |          |
|         +---------------------+          |
| Overlay (image with alpha on top)        |
| visible on focus or press, NOT clickable |
+------------------------------------------+
```

So basically there may be other items under the overlay image which should still be fully accessible, e.g. by clicking & dragging.

Do you know how I may solve this in Android? A XML layout solution would be the best! Any best practices here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do you know how I may solve this in Android?

Things that are on top from a Z-axis standpoint get the input events. Hence, your choices would appear to be:

1. Create an immediate subclass of `View` where you do everything yourself, dispensing with the `ImageButton` (or whatever it is you are using now).
2. Attempt to create a composite custom `View` and delegate relevant input events to the underneath widgets, which may or may not be possible.
3. Find some way of achieving an acceptable look that does not imply having something over top of the button.

I am assuming that by "button" you mean an `ImageButton` where you have replaced the background to be your own `StateListDrawable` -- otherwise, nothing you wrote here makes much sense to me.

If so, you do not need an overlay. You can get by with an...ummmm...underlay. Make the underlay (a separate `ImageView`) visible or invisible based upon the button state. Make the `ImageView`'s face and background look "shining" as part of your `StateListDrawables`.

Comment: @mreichelt: You might also consider going with a look more like this: http://blog.tomgibara.com/post/2149115454/dynamic-android-texture

Comment: So instead of an `ImageButton` I have an `ImageView` because I am using a custom image as a clickable area. When this ImageView is clicked a flare should appear on top of it which is larger than the first image. As you said I might use a StateListDrawable as a background, but that of course appears in the background. It shouldn't get the input events even if it's on top because it's neither clickable nor focusable. I could do a workaround with 2 ImageViews (the flare on top), but that would increase the view hierarchy. A custom view also is not so desired for this IMHO common use case…